# What's the best IDE and language to create a FA2 Token?

Tags: tezos-client, smartpy

Does SmartPy provide the best interface to do it?

https://smartpy.io/ide?template=FA2.py
Does this example provide everything you need to create your own token?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to be less about opinions and "best" but about providing answers to specific technical questions you have. For example, "What IDE and smart contract languages can be used to create and FA2 Token?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the FA2 template provides everything you need to create a Financial Asset.

Feel free to join [SmartPy telegram](https://t.me/SmartPy_io)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the Ligo Ide online editor
https://ide.ligolang.org/

Comment: please provide more detail in your answer that directly addresses the FA2 creation being asked about